# publish a message on facebook without user approval

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I would like to post to facebook a message without having to request the users approval.

Can this be done with integrated Windows Phone tools or must i access manually the facebook api? I see that `ShareLinkTask` requires your approval, are there alternatives?

**UPDATE** i would like this feature to post scores and achievements and not have to bother the user.

Comment: "without having to request the users approval" - evil application. -1...

Comment: you have to request permission via the API to access users profile on facebook.

Comment: i would like to post scores and things like that! not spam etc.

Comment: you still have to have the correct permissions.  You cant just skip over facebooks authentication procedures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to request permission via the API to access users profile on facebook.  Posting to a users wall or sending them a message without any approval would be bypassing facebook's platform policy and should facebook find out about this activity they will surely shut down your application and possibly block your developer account.
**NOT** recommended.
You should ask for the correct permissions from your users and act according to the policy of the platform on witch you are developing.